# Randomisation macro - need the data from multiple columns produced, not just the first column

Tags: vba, macos, range

This tool produces a random set of 10 claim numbers - but I have other data corresponding to those claim numbers that I'd also like displayed.

It produces the 10 random claim numbers but instead of just producing the claim numbers from Column A, I'd like it to also display the corresponding Benefit Type (column B) and the Claim Status (column C)

```
Sub RandomSelectionClaimsND()

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim destSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim destRange As Range
    Dim numRows As Integer
    Dim selectedRows() As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    
    ' Set the source and destination sheets
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Claims data")
    Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Claims ND")
    
    ' Set the source range to the first column of the source sheet
    Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("A:A")
    
    ' Determine the number of rows in the source range
    numRows = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, sourceRange.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Create an array to hold the row numbers of the selected items
    ReDim selectedRows(1 To 10)
    
    ' Select ten random rows
    For i = 1 To 10
        ' Generate a random row number between 1 and the number of rows in the source range
        selectedRows(i) = Int((numRows - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
        
        ' Check if this row has already been selected
        For j = 1 To i - 1
            If selectedRows(i) = selectedRows(j) Then
                ' If it has, generate a new row number and try again
                i = i - 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    ' Sort the selected rows in ascending order
    Call BubbleSort(selectedRows, 10)
    
    ' Copy the selected rows to the destination sheet
    Set destRange = destSheet.Range("A:A")
    For i = 1 To 10
        sourceRange.Cells(selectedRows(i), 1).Copy destRange.Cells(i + 1, 1)
    Next i
    
End Sub

Sub BubbleSort(arr() As Integer, n As Integer)
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim temp As Integer
    
    For i = 1 To n - 1
        For j = i + 1 To n
            If arr(i) > arr(j) Then
                temp = arr(i)
                arr(i) = arr(j)
                arr(j) = temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `sourceRange.Cells(selectedRows(i), 2).Copy destRange.Cells(i + 1, 2)` etc if you have other cells to copy.  Or just `sourceRange.Cells(selectedRows(i), 1).Resize(1, 3).Copy destRange.Cells(i + 1, 1)` if you want to copy columns A to C

Comment: Works brilliantly - thank you!! @TimWilliams

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy more cells you could add (eg)

```
sourceRange.Cells(selectedRows(i), 2).Copy destRange.Cells(i + 1, 2) 
sourceRange.Cells(selectedRows(i), 3).Copy destRange.Cells(i + 1, 3)
```

Or (since your cells are adjacent):

```
sourceRange.Cells(selectedRows(i), 1).Resize(1, 3).Copy destRange.Cells(i + 1, 1)
```